# How can compute for the product of an array?

Tags: java, android

My codes goes this way...It gives an output of zero...Please help me..thanks in advance:)

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView inputValues = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_input);

    final TextView GeoMean= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_GeoMean);

    Button btnCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
    btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        @Override
        public void onClick(View agr0) {

String []values = ( inputValues.getText().toString().split(","));
    int [] convertedValues = new int[values.length];

                int product=1;
                    for(int a = 1; a <=convertedValues.length; a++){

                   product*=convertedValues[a];
               }


                tv_product.setText(Double.toString(product));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below changes should do the trick for you:-

```
for(int a = 0; a <convertedValues.length; a++){ // "a from 1" to "a<=n" will give an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    convertedValues[a] = Integer.parseInt(values[a]); // Transfer value from "values" to "convertedValues"
    product*=convertedValues[a];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It gives an output of zero..
```

*Because here* `int[] convertedValues = new int[values.length];`

*all values of* `convertedValues` *are default* i.e. 0

*and here you are using* `product*=convertedValues[a]; // first time`1*0`then`0*0`etc`

*Use following code :*

```
for (int a = 0; a < convertedValues.length; a++) {
            convertedValues[a]=Integer.parseInt(values[a]);// Just add this Line
            product *= convertedValues[a];
    }
```

*Now See the Magic*

Answer (score 0):

`int [] convertedValues = new int[values.length];` This statement create an int array with length = `values.length`.

It will not store the values which are being read. You can do like this to achieve what you want :

```
String []values = ( inputValues.getText().toString().split(","));
    int [] convertedValues = new int[values.length];
    int i=0;
    for(String temp:values){
        convertedValues[i++] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With regard to:

```
String []values = ( inputValues.getText().toString().split(","));
int [] convertedValues = new int[values.length];
```

You create an integer array of the same size but the thing that seems to be missing is the transfer of the information from `values` to `convertedValues`.

Without that transfer, the integer array maintains its initial state, which is an array of zero values.

You'll need to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    convertedValues[i] = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
```

(zero-based arrays in Java, not one-based as you seem to think, and making sure you catch the `NumberFormatException` in case the string isn't valid) before trying to use it but it's probably not necessary to create a whole new array. You could probably just modify your calculation loop to be:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= values.length; i++)
    product *= Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
```

So, in terms of the whole code segment, the following would probably be a good starting point:

```
String[] values = inputValues.getText().toString().split(",");
int product = 1;
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        product *= Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    product = 0; // or something more suitable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just see a new int array.. where do you put values in it ? i.e after the statement int [] convertedValues = new int[values.length];